# Como posso gerar um código hexadecimal a partir de outra sequência de números?

Tags: android, hexadecimal

Estou fazendo um app gerador de código, preciso gerar um código hexadecimal a partir do código digitado pelo usuário e mostrar este código hexadecimal gerado. Alguém poderia me explicar como posso chegar a isso? Sou iniciante nessa área.

Comment: Em que linguagem? Nas linguagens que entendem máscaras do printf(), você poderia fazer algo como printf("%x", numero);

Comment: A princípio a solução dessa pergunta (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java) funciona, já chegou a tentar?

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem uma string com um número qualquer, por exemplo:

```
String str = "43956";
```

Você deve primeiro converter isso para um número inteiro, assim:

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(str).intValue();
```

Em seguida pode converter esse número para uma string de dígitos hexadecimais, assim:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(num);
```

Agora é uma questão de organizar sua UI para exibir esse valor.

As documentações:

[`Integer.valueOf(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)
[`Integer.intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--)
[`Integer.toHexString(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-)